# Is it possible to access the decoder and encoder of a compiled and trained GAN generator?

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to convert an autoencoder for facial exchange applications into using GANs. I've studied some approaches by other users(https://github.com/FaceAR/faceswap-1/tree/master/plugins/Model_GAN), but am unfamiliar with how accessible GAN components are.

Essentially, I'd like to know if it's possible to access the decoder and encoder components of a GAN's generator in Keras, post compile and post training.

Essentially, both approaches define an encoder and a decoder, following which an autoencoder can be built as follows:

```
netGA = Model(x, decoder_A(encoder(x)))
```

With the autoencoder approach, we can then use the decoders of different subjects on an encoded representation to perform a facial swap by calling .predict() accordingly. Weights can be loaded into the encoder and decoder components separately.

This can be illustrated with the following model (you'll notice that the weights of the decoder and encoder are saved separately, and both objects can be called separately)

```
class dfModel():
    def __init__(self):

        self.model_dir = sav_Model
        self.pretrained_weight=pretrained_weight
        self.encoder = self.Encoder()
        self.decoder_A = self.Decoder()
        self.decoder_B = self.Decoder()

        self.initModel()


    def initModel(self):
        optimizer = Adam(lr=5e-5, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999) #orig adam 5e-5
        x = Input(shape=IMAGE_SHAPE)

        self.autoencoder_A = KerasModel(x, self.decoder_A(self.encoder(x)))
        self.autoencoder_B = KerasModel(x, self.decoder_B(self.encoder(x)))
        print(self.encoder.summary())
        print(self.decoder_A.summary())


        self.autoencoder_A.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_absolute_error')
        self.autoencoder_B.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_absolute_error')

    def converter(self, swap):
        autoencoder = self.autoencoder_B if not swap else self.autoencoder_A 
        return lambda img: autoencoder.predict(img)

    def conv(self, filters):
        def block(x):
            x = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
            x = LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
            return x
        return block

    def upscale(self, filters):
        def block(x):
            x = Conv2D(filters * 4, kernel_size=3, padding='same')(x)
            x = LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
            x = PixelShuffler()(x)
            #Pixelshufflers job here is analoguous to upsampling2d
            return x
        return block

    def Encoder(self):
        input_ = Input(shape=IMAGE_SHAPE)
        x = input_
        x = self.conv(128)(x)
        x = self.conv(256)(x)
        x = self.conv(512)(x)
        x = self.conv(1024)(x)
        x = Dense(ENCODER_DIM)(Flatten()(x))
        x = Dense(4 * 4 * 1024)(x)
        #Passed flattened X input into 2 dense layers, 1024 and 1024*4*4
        x = Reshape((4, 4, 1024))(x)
        #Reshapes X into 4,4,1024
        x = self.upscale(512)(x)
        return KerasModel(input_, x)

    def Decoder(self):
        input_ = Input(shape=(8, 8, 512))
        x = input_
        x = self.upscale(256)(x) #Actually 1024 given filters*4
        x = self.upscale(128)(x) #Actually 512
        x = self.upscale(64)(x) #Actually 256
        x = Conv2D(3, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(x)
        return KerasModel(input_, x)

    def load(self, swapped):
        (face_A,face_B) = (decoder_AH5, decoder_BH5) if not swapped else (decoder_BH5, decoder_AH5)

        try:
            self.encoder.load_weights(self.pretrained_weight + encoderH5)
            self.decoder_A.load_weights(self.pretrained_weight + face_A)
            self.decoder_B.load_weights(self.pretrained_weight + face_B)
            print('loaded model weights')
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print('Failed loading existing training data.')
            print(e)
            return False

    def save_weights(self):
        self.encoder.save_weights(self.model_dir + encoderH5)
        self.decoder_A.save_weights(self.model_dir + decoder_AH5)
        self.decoder_B.save_weights(self.model_dir + decoder_BH5)
        print('saved model weights')
```

However, the GAN-based model is significantly more complex. Note how the weights are saved for the entire autoencoder, instead of by components here.

```
class GANModel():
    def __init__(self):

        self.IMAGE_SHAPE = (64, 64, 3)

        self.model_dir = sav_Model
        self.pretrained_weight=pretrained_weight
        self.encoder = self.Encoder()
        self.decoder_A = self.Decoder()
        self.decoder_B = self.Decoder()


        self.netDA, self.netDB = self.build_discriminator()


        self.initModel()


    def one_minus(x): return 1 - x


    def initModel(self):
        optimizer = Adam(lr=5e-5, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999) #orig adam 5e-5
        x = Input(shape=IMAGE_SHAPE)


        ##All of the following is done in build discriminator in the original code

        encoder = self.Encoder(self.IMAGE_SHAPE)
        decoder_A = self.Decoder(self.IMAGE_SHAPE)
        decoder_B = self.Decoder(self.IMAGE_SHAPE)    

        netGA = Model(x, decoder_A(encoder(x)))
        netGB = Model(x, decoder_B(encoder(x)))

        try:
            netGA.load_weights(str(self.model_dir / netGAH5))
            netGB.load_weights(str(self.model_dir / netGBH5))
            print ("Generator models loaded.")
        except:
            print ("Generator weights files not found.")
            pass
        #return netGA, netGB,   Return function is pointless here as we are still within the function



        self.netDA.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
        self.netDB.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

        #Moved these after DA compile so that the training of DA can actually take place during DA training
        self.netDA.trainable = False
        self.netDB.trainable = False

        # Build and compile the generator

        self.netGA.compile(loss=['mae', 'mse'], optimizer=optimizer)
        self.netGB.compile(loss=['mae', 'mse'], optimizer=optimizer)

        img = Input(shape=self.IMAGE_SHAPE)

        alphaA, reconstructed_imgA = self.netGA(img)
        alphaB, reconstructed_imgB = self.netGB(img)

        masked_imgA = add([multiply([alphaA, reconstructed_imgA]), multiply([Lambda(one_minus)(alphaA), img])])
        masked_imgB = add([multiply([alphaB, reconstructed_imgB]), multiply([Lambda(one_minus)(alphaB), img])])
        out_discriminatorA = self.netDA(concatenate([masked_imgA, img], axis=-1))
        out_discriminatorB = self.netDB(concatenate([masked_imgB, img], axis=-1))

        # The adversarial_autoencoder model  (stacked generator and discriminator) takes
        # img as input => generates encoded represenation and reconstructed image => determines validity 
        self.adversarial_autoencoderA = Model(img, [reconstructed_imgA, out_discriminatorA])
        self.adversarial_autoencoderB = Model(img, [reconstructed_imgB, out_discriminatorB])

        self.adversarial_autoencoderA.compile(loss=['mae', 'mse'],
                                              loss_weights=[1, 0.5],
                                              optimizer=optimizer)
        self.adversarial_autoencoderB.compile(loss=['mae', 'mse'],
                                              loss_weights=[1, 0.5],
                                              optimizer=optimizer)

    def converter(self, swap):
        autoencoder = self.netGB if not swap else self.netGA
        return lambda img: predictor.predict(img)

    def conv(self, filters):
        def block(x):
            x = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
            x = LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
            return x
        return block

    def conv_res(self,filters):
        def block(x):

            input_tensor = x
            x = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
            x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
            x = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(x)
            # x = add([x,input_tensor])
            x = LeakyReLU(0.2)(x)
            return x
        return block


    def upscale(self, filters):
        def block(x):
            x = Conv2D(filters * 4, kernel_size=3, padding='same')(x)
            x = LeakyReLU(0.1)(x)
            x = PixelShuffler()(x)
            #Pixelshufflers job here is analoguous to upsampling2d
            return x
        return block

    def Encoder(IMAGE_SHAPE):
        input_ = Input(shape=IMAGE_SHAPE)
        x = input_
        x = self.conv(128)(x)
        x = self.conv(256)(x)
        x = self.conv(512)(x)
        x = self.conv(1024)(x)
        x = Dense(ENCODER_DIM)(Flatten()(x))
        x = Dense(4 * 4 * 1024)(x)
        #Passed flattened X input into 2 dense layers, 1024 and 1024*4*4
        x = Reshape((4, 4, 1024))(x)
        #Reshapes X into 4,4,1024
        x = self.upscale(512)(x)
        return KerasModel(input_, x)

    def Decoder(IMAGE_SHAPE):
        input_ = Input(shape=(8, 8, 512))
        x = input_
        x = self.upscale(256)(x) #Actually 1024 given filters*4
        x = self.upscale(128)(x) #Actually 512
        x = self.upscale(64)(x) #Actually 256
        x= self.conv_res(64)(x)
        x= self.conv_res(64)(x)
        alpha = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='sigmoid')(x)
        rgb = Conv2D(3, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='tanh')(x)
        return KerasModel(input_, [alpha, rgb])



    def build_discriminator(self):  
        def conv_block_d(input_tensor, f, use_instance_norm=True):
            x = input_tensor
            x = Conv2D(f, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same")(x)
            x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(x)
            return x

        def Discriminator(IMAGE_SHAPE):
            inp = Input(shape=(IMAGE_SHAPE[0], IMAGE_SHAPE[1], IMAGE_SHAPE[2]*2))
            x = conv_block_d(inp, 64, False)
            x = conv_block_d(x, 128, False)
            x = conv_block_d(x, 256, False)
            out = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=4, padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(x)   
            return Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=out) 

        netDA = Discriminator(self.IMAGE_SHAPE)
        netDB = Discriminator(self.IMAGE_SHAPE)     

        try:
            netDA.load_weights(str(self.model_dir / netDAH5))
            netDB.load_weights(str(self.model_dir / netDBH5))
            print ("Discriminator models loaded.")
        except:
            print ("Discriminator weights files not found.")
            pass


        return netDA, netDB 




    def load(self, swapped):
        return True
    def save_weights(self):
        self.encoder.save_weights(self.model_dir + encoderH5)
        self.decoder_A.save_weights(self.model_dir + decoder_AH5)
        self.decoder_B.save_weights(self.model_dir + decoder_BH5)
        print('saved encoder and decoder weights')
        #Save a few more weights 
        self.netGA.save_weights(str(self.model_dir / netGAH5))
        self.netGB.save_weights(str(self.model_dir /  netGBH5))
        self.netDA.save_weights(str(self.model_dir /  netDAH5))
        self.netDB.save_weights(str(self.model_dir /  netDBH5))
        print ("saved generator and discriminator weights")
```

Would the same be possible with a GAN's generator model, where the weights are loaded in a single instance across an entire generator?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you want to know... is this a general ("framework-agnostic") question? In that case: for sure that's possible. Or is it rather a framework specific question like "how to do this in keras?"? In that case please formulate the question accordingly and add a tag for the framework. That way, experts in that particular framework will more easily identify your question in the feed and an answer is much more likely.

Comment: good suggestion, apologies, reformatting now